# BASH Linux - How to pass the result of find into a mv destination via echo

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory which is filled with PDFS that were uploaded by a user and that didnt realize that certain naming conventions needed to be followed to have the files be downloadable again. To fix the issue en mass, I need to run a bash script or command that will recursively spider through the subdirectories and strip out the bad characters and rename the files.

I thought I had it all figured out, but alas, I am stuck on one part. Once I run my command (see below) I get a host of errors showing its finding the files, but the argument list for move (the destination) isnt being set properly. How do I pass the filename into the sub-command?

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -or -name '*.PDF' -execdir mv -v '{}' `echo {} | tr ' ' '_' | tr -d '[{}(),\!]' | tr -d "\'" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | sed 's/_-_/_/g'`\;
```

I know my issue is the echo {} thing, but I have no idea how to get the filename found by find in there. The first substitution works, the echo one doesnt.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That fails because the bits inside the backticks is evaluated and substituted into the command line before `find` is even started. You might want to look into `rename` instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) helpfully points out three issues with your command:

1. Your `-execdir` [ignores everything](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2146) before the `-or`
2. Your `\;` has to be [a separate argument](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2067)
3. Your `` `..` `` will [expand once](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2014) before find runs, not per file found.

Additionally,

- The {} in the `tr` is interpretted by find
- `tr` arguments should not have `[]` around them

Accounting for all this:

```
find . \( -name '*.pdf' -or -name '*.PDF' \) \
    -execdir sh -c 'mv -v "$1" "$(echo "$1" | tr " " "_" | tr -d "{()},\!'\''" | tr "A-Z" "a-z" | sed "s/_-_/_/g")"' _ {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because your command substitution (delimited by the backticks) is done before the `find` command is executed, so `{}` is not yet available. I'd suggest restructuring your command by pulling out the substitutions to a loop that iterates over `find`'s results:

```
find . -print0 -name '*.pdf' -or -name '*.PDF' | 
while read -d $'\0' -r name ; do
    pushd $( dirname "$name" ) &>/dev/null
    newname=$( tr ' ' '_' <<<"$name" | 
               tr -d '[{}(),\!]' | 
               tr -d "\'" | 
               tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | 
               sed 's/_-_/_/g' )
    mv "$name" "$newname"
    popd &>/dev/null
done
```

The `find` command in this example used the `print0` option to separate its results with `\0` characters. `read` in the loop's head is instructed to ignore escape sequences (`-r`) and use the `\0` characters as delimiters (`-d`). `pushd` and `popd` are used to emulate `find`'s `-execdir` behavior that you had in your original command.

Answer (score -3):

Pipe one command into another like this:

```
command1 | command2
```